# JavaScript - Close submenu if user selects another menu item or clicks outside of menu

Tags: javascript, menu

I'm trying to figure out how to close sub menu drop downs, if a user selects another menu or clicks outside of the menu (clicks something else on the page). I've read and tried a few different ways, but haven't gotten anywhere. I Just confused myself as to what is the best or right approach. Using regular JavaScript only - trying to learn.

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <ul id="filters">
        <li><a href="#" class="filterBtn">one</a>
            <ul class="dropM">
                <li>I belong to one</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="filterBtn">two</a>
            <ul class="dropM">
                <li>I belong to two</li>
            </ul>           
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="filterBtn">three</a>
            <ul class="dropM">
                <li>I belong to three</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="filterBtn">four</a>
            <ul class="dropM">
                <li>I belong to four</li>
            </ul>           
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:#ffc600;
  font-family:'helvetica neue';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
div.container {padding: 10px; background: #bada55; text-align: center;}
div.inner-wrap {margin: 0 auto; position: relative; display: inline-block;} 

ul#filters { list-style: none;}
ul#filters li {display: inline-block; position: relative;}
ul#filters li > ul.dropM {list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: -40px; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fff; display: block; min-width: 200px; display: none; z-index: 201;}
ul#filters li > ul.dropM.open {display: block;}
ul#filters {display: inline-block;}
ul#filters li a.filterBtn {text-decoration: none; padding: 10px 20px; background: #ccc; color: black;}
```

JS

```
    const filterMenuBtn = document.querySelectorAll('a.filterBtn');
const dropMenu = document.querySelectorAll('ul.dropM');

function openDropMenu(e){
    filterMenuBtn.forEach(cliks => {
      //console.log(cliks);
      if(cliks === this) {
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open');
        //console.log('i clicked this one');
      }
    });
}

filterMenuBtn.forEach(cliks => cliks.addEventListener('click', openDropMenu));
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sparrow128/tpjL3Ln4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=tpjL3Ln4)

Comment: You know that probably you have a typo in your code around? Cliks should be clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your javascript to this

```
const filterMenuBtn = document.querySelectorAll('a.filterBtn');
const dropMenu = document.querySelectorAll('ul.dropM');

function openDropMenu(e) {
if (e.type == 'click'){
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open');
} else {
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('open');
}
}

filterMenuBtn.forEach(cliks => cliks.addEventListener('click', openDropMenu));
filterMenuBtn.forEach(cliks => cliks.addEventListener('blur', openDropMenu));
```

Comment: thank you - I tried adding that after the click event listener, and it didn't work. The menus still open on click, but do not close when something else is clicked. Is it possible to combine a click and blur on an addEventListner?I wasn't able to find anything like that.

Comment: @sparrow I edited the answer. Please check if it works.

Comment: thank you! It works, I just had to move the 'blur" event listener before the 'click' listener. I had tried the 'else' with r.emove inside of the 'if' within filterMenuBtn.forEach earlier, but it didn't work (I still need to figure out why and understand it didn't work). This is a lot more understandable to me - Thanks again!