# Close submenus of one menu item when another menu item's button ('cousin' of first) is clicked with Javascript and no jQuery

Tags: javascript, menu

I have a clickable/tappable menu (it can have infinite levels) in pure html, css (no Bootstrap), vanilla javascript and NO jQuery.

When I click on a button linked to a menu item with a submenu it opens the submenu and when I click the button again it closes the submenu. All well and good.

However, what I can't figure out is how to close already open submenu(s) when I click on another top level main item's button (what I would call the element's 'cousin': the element's parent's sibling's child) to open its submenu. So I end up with two or more submenus open side by side and overlapping.

I have tried a version of the answer here: [Stackoverflow.com question 41202059](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202059/javascript-close-submenu-if-user-selects-another-menu-item-or-clicks-outside-o) which seems to be the closest to what I am trying to do, but without success.

Here is my snippet:

```js
/// this script opens the sub-menu when the li button is clicked
document.getElementById("menucontent").addEventListener("click", openSubMenu);
function openSubMenu(event){
    if(event.target.type === "button"){
    event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
    event.target.classList.add("clicked");
    event.target.classList.remove("not-clicked");
    }
}
// this script switches the triangle direction when the button is clicked
document.getElementById("menucontent").addEventListener("click", triangle);
function triangle(event){
    if(event.target.type === "button"){
    event.target.classList.toggle("triangle");
    }
}
// this script closes the submenus when clicking anywhere outside the menu and reverts the triangle to pointing down
document.getElementById("mainbody").addEventListener("click", closeMenu);
function closeMenu(event) {
    if(event.target.type != "button") {
    var level1 = document.getElementsByClassName("level-1");
    var level2 = document.getElementsByClassName("level-2");
    var btnlevel1 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-level-1");
    var btnlevel2 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-level-2");
        for (var i = 0; i < level1.length; i++) {
        level1[i].classList.add("hidden"); }
        for (var i = 0; i < level2.length; i++) {
        level2[i].classList.add("hidden"); }
        for (var i = 0; i < btnlevel1.length; i++){
        btnlevel1[i].classList.remove("triangle");
        btnlevel1[i].classList.remove("clicked");}
        for (var i = 0; i < btnlevel2.length; i++) {
        btnlevel2[i].classList.remove("triangle");
        btnlevel2[i].classList.remove("clicked");}
    }
}
document.getElementById("mainbody").addEventListener("click", addClass);
function addClass(event) {
// the click is triggered outside the menu
    if(event.target.type != 'button') {
// these are top level buttons only
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-level-1.clicked');
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].classList.add('not-clicked');
        buttons[i].classList.remove('clicked'); }
    }
}
```

```css
.outer {
 border: 2px solid gray;
 margin: 1rem;
 padding: 1rem; 
}
.stickymenuwrapper {
 background-color: #fff;
 transition-duration: 0s;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 995;
 }
.scrabble-menu .hidden {
 display: none;
}
.scrabble-menu .navbar > li {
 display: inline-block;
}
.scrabble-menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 0;
}
.scrabble-menu ul.navbar {
 background-color: pink;
 padding: 0 1rem;
}
.scrabble-menu li ul {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 background-color: pink;
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}
.scrabble-menu ul.level-2,
.scrabble-menu ul.level-3 {
 background-color: yellow;
 top: 0%;
 left: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
 }
.scrabble-menu ul.level-3 {
 background-color: orange;
 } 
.scrabble-menu li.active > a {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.scrabble-menu a.separator:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 }
.scrabble-menu button,
.scrabble-menu button:focus {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 height: 2.5rem;
 width: 1.75rem;
 outline:none;
 padding: 0;
}
.scrabble-menu li {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 1.5rem;
}
.scrabble-menu .navbar > li > a {
 padding: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0.5rem;
 margin-left: 1rem;
}
.scrabble-menu .navbar > li:first-child > a {
 padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.scrabble-menu li button:after {
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 position: relative;
 right: -3px;
 top: 0;
}  
.scrabble-menu ul.level-1 > li a {
 padding-top: 0.5rem;
}
.scrabble-menu li button[class^="btn-level"]:after {
 content: "\25B6";
 cursor: pointer;
}
.scrabble-menu .triangle{
}
.scrabble-menu li button[class^="btn-level"].triangle:after {
 content: "\25C0";
}
.scrabble-menu li button.btn-level-1:after {
 content: "\25BC";
}
.scrabble-menu li button.btn-level-1.triangle:after {
 content: "\25B2";
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbody" class="outer">This is a menu that works with pure html, css and vanilla Javascript. There is no jQuery.<br>There is JS to close the menu when clicking outside the menu and to close each open submenu when its parent's button is clicked. The arrows (including for submenus) switch accordingly.
<div class="row sticky-main-menu">
    <div id="stickymenuwrapper" class="col stickymenuwrapper scrabble-menu">
    <ul id="menucontent" class="navbar">
<li class="item-101 single current active">
<a href="/" class="one">HOME</a></li>
<li class="item-122 single divider deeper parent">
<a class="two">TEST TWO</a>
<button class="btn-level-1" type="button"></button>
<ul id="drop-122" class="hidden level-1">
    <li class="item-121 single">
    <a href="/" class="">Test level 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="item-103 single deeper parent">
<a href="/" class="two">ABOUT</a>
<button class="btn-level-1" type="button"></button>
<ul class="level-1 hidden">
    <li class="item-104 single">
    <a href="/" class="">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-104 single">
    <a href="/" class="">More</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: a simple and sure solution is to close all menus except current, or even simpler close all menus and open current

Comment: If I just click a menu item's button to view the submenu then the item isn't current, is it? Or do you mean add a click event that closes everything first and then opens the one I clicked?

Comment: it depends on your design and implementation you can make it current or handle menus which have submenus differently both are easy to implement

Comment: 'Easy' if you're not a Javascript beginner, perhaps!

Comment: for example menus which have submenus can have a specific css class, so testing this both in javascript and css is not difficult

Comment: My submenus and buttons all have a class based on their parent's item level, e.g. top level buttons have `class="btn-level-1" ` and same level ULs have `class="level-1" ` and so on, but what I call 'cousins', i.e. two menu item buttons with ULs on the same level have the same class. (See my snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have streamlined the code a little and now delegate from the wrapper

```js
function openLowerMenu(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('test1', tgt.type === "button");
  e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.add('test2', tgt.type !== "button");
}

document.getElementById("stickymenuwrapper").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type==="button") {
    const level = tgt.className.replace(/[^\d]/g,"");
    [...document.querySelectorAll('ul.level-'+level)].forEach(ul => ul.classList.add("hidden"));
    const show = tgt.classList.contains("triangle")
    tgt.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden",!show); 
    tgt.classList.toggle("triangle",!show);
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.outer {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sticky-main-menu {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.stickymenuwrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition-duration: 0s;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 995;
}

.scrabble-menu .hidden {
  display: none;
}

.scrabble-menu .navbar>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.scrabble-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}

.scrabble-menu ul.navbar {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  /* text-align: center;*/
}

.scrabble-menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

.scrabble-menu ul.level-2,
.scrabble-menu ul.level-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0%;
  left: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.scrabble-menu ul.level-3 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.scrabble-menu li.active>a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.scrabble-menu a.separator:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.scrabble-menu button,
.scrabble-menu button:focus {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 1.75rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.scrabble-menu li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.scrabble-menu .navbar>li>a {
  padding: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.scrabble-menu .navbar>li:first-child>a {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}


/* separator line code here */

.scrabble-menu li button:after {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: relative;
  right: -3px;
  top: 0;
}

.scrabble-menu ul.level-1>li a {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

.scrabble-menu li button[class^="btn-level"]:after {
  content: "\25B6";
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrabble-menu li button[class^="btn-level"].triangle:after {
  content: "\25C0";
}

.scrabble-menu li button.btn-level-1:after {
  content: "\25B2";
}

.scrabble-menu li button.btn-level-1.triangle:after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

.scrabble-menu li button.btn-level-1.triangle2:after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

.scrabble-menu .clicked {}

.scrabble-menu li button[class^="btn-level"].not-clicked:after {
  content: "\25B0";
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrabble-menu li button.btn-level-1.not-clicked::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}
```

```html
<div class="row sticky-main-menu">
  <div id="stickymenuwrapper" class="col stickymenuwrapper scrabble-menu">
    <ul id="menucontent" class="scrabblemenu navbar">
      <li class="item-122 single divider deeper parent">
        <a class="two">ITEM ONE</a>
        <button class="btn-level-1 triangle" type="button"></button>
        <ul id="drop-122" class="hidden level-1">
          <li class="item-121 single">
            <a href="/" class="">Item One level 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item-134 single deeper parent">
            <a class="nav-header two">Item One level 2 menu heading</a>
            <button class="btn-level-2" type="button"></button>
            <ul id="drop-134" class="level-2 hidden">
              <li class="item-135 single">
                <a href="/" class="">Article under menu heading</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-122 single divider deeper parent">
        <a class="two">ITEM TWO</a>
        <button class="btn-level-1 triangle" type="button"></button>
        <ul id="drop-122" class="hidden level-1">
          <li class="item-121 single">
            <a href="/" class="">Item Two level 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="item-134 single deeper parent">
            <a class="nav-header two">Item Two level 2 menu heading</a>
            <button class="btn-level-2" type="button"></button>
            <ul id="drop-134" class="level-2 hidden">
              <li class="item-135 single">
                <a href="/" class="">Article under menu heading</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-103 single deeper parent">
        <a href="/" class="two">ITEM THREE WITH LINK</a>
        <button class="btn-level-1 triangle" type="button"></button>
        <ul class="not-separator level-1 hidden">
          <li class="item-104 single">
            <a href="/" class="">Article under Item Three</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a class="two separator">Item Three Level 2 separator</a>
            <button class="btn-level-2" type="button"></button>
            <ul id="drop-107" class="level-2 hidden">
              <li class="item-108 single">
                <a href="/" class="">Lower article</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brillian! Thank you so much. One question: what is the significance of the three dots  here: `[...document.querySelectorAll ` ?

Comment: It is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the html collection into an array. This is to allow older edge browsers to use map/forEach because they do not support forEach and map on the collection

Comment: Thank you. One more step on the way of learning Javascript.

Comment: Coming back to this today, I realise that although the submenu closes when I click another main item's button - which is what I asked for, of course - I can now no longer close the submenu with its own button. :-( If you run my original code snippet you'll see this working.

Comment: Ok, I missed that one. I’ll fix that in a few hours

Comment: Thank you! I also have code that switches the triangles around when the button is clicked. And also to close the menu when when clicking outside. I've updated my original snippet to show this in case it causes any more conflicts.

Comment: Sorry - bedtime here. Illl try tomorrow. It’s not difficult

Comment: Ok simplified this further. Level 1 toggles and toggles the triangle too. I'll continue in 10 hours or so

Comment: the logic you use in the HTML is far too complex. I managed to generalise, but cannot figure out why the sub-level2 behaves opposite from level1

Comment: Do you mean the position of the next level? That's just CSS. You can ignore the lower levels. I just want the first level of submenu (level-1) to close when a btn-level-1 is clicked - either its own sibling button or another item's btn-level-1.